# Node.js - Command npm run dev is stuck on message "Compilation complete. Watching for file changes"

Tags: node.js

When I launch `npm run dev` on my project, the process is stuck on the message below:

> Compilation complete. Watching for file changes

and the server is not started.

I have the problem only on my Windows. When I launch the same command on my Ubuntu virtual machine, the server start as expected.

Do you know what how could I investigate more, have some logs or indications about the "error" ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

can you post your package.json file?
it is important, your script part is definded like that:

```
{
  "name": "snail",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "dev":"node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",

    "debug": "~2.6.9",
  }
}
```

app.js is the filename of yout startfile.

Comment: {
  "name": "swm-craft-ai-mock",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tslint --project . & tsc",
    "dev": "tsc --watch & nodemon dist",
    "test": "tsc && mocha dist/**/*.spec.js",
    "lint": "tslint --project .",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "craft-ai": "1.11.1",
    "es6-promise": "4.2.4",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.0-beta2",
    "nodemon": "1.11.0",
    "typed-rest-client": "^1.0.7"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.1.2",
    "@types/express": "4.11.1",
    "@types/jsonpath": "0.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "7.0.22",
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "jsonpath": "1.0.0",
    "mocha": "3.4.2",
    "mongodb-uri": "^0.9.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.9",
    "supertest": "3.0.0",
    "tsc": "1.20150623.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  }
}